# How to tell what is the right css line to apply in nested classes

Tags: css

Here is my inspect element view: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4wxq7

I want to apply styles to `class="lyrics"`

I am using on my css like this

```css
.postcontent .lyrics { styles... }
```

but it is not working.

What is the proper css line to target that class. This is inside a wordpress post. Basically, I want to be able to style a certain content of the post and not affect others.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML the parent div has the class `post-content` and not `postcontent`.

So you'll need to change the class in your HTML to `postcontent` or change the CSS:

```
.post-content .lyrics { styles... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as :

```
.post-content .lyrics { styles... }
```

OR if you want that your style should not get overridden by other CSS, use ID parent selector as:

```
#content .lyrics { styles... }
```

EDIT: Check the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SmH6B/

Comment: Did not work for me. I applied this on my style.css #content .lyrics { color:#000000!important; } but my text is still white

Comment: actually .post-content .lyrics works but I was trying #content .lyrics because you mention that it will not be overwritten. thanks

Comment: In general css with ID selectors override those with class selectors. In your case, it did not work possibly because you have two div with id 'content'. Maybe you can add another parent to avoid conflict, try this: " #et_page_content #content .lyrics { styles... } ". This should work for you.